# Hover image in datatables row only works on 1e page

Tags: datatables

I uses Datatables and add to a rowcel an image with an event. Everything works fine on the first page of pagination , when I move the mouse over the tumbnail the image is hover and I see a big image.

On the second page the event is gone, and the hover don't work. I read that DataTables removes nodes from the DOM. Does anybody know how it can work on all the pages?

```
<td><a href="../images/redcont/123.jpg" class="hover"><img src="../images/redcont/123_tumb.jpg" class="mediabank-preview-thumbnail"/></a></td>
```

The code for the event is:

```
    // Hover images
    var offsetX = 20;
    var offsetY = -400;
    $('a.hover').hover(function(e){ 
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $('<img id="largeImage" src="' + href + '" alt="image" />')
        .css({'top':e.pageY + offsetY,'left':e.pageX + offsetX})
        .appendTo('body');
    }, function(){
        $('#largeImage').remove();
    });
    $('a.hover').mousemove(function(e){
        $('#largeImage').css({'top':e.pageY + offsetY,'left':e.pageX + offsetX});
    });
    $('a.hover').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

This results in the following outputcode in the browser:

[image]

But on the second page from the pagination the event is gone.

My total code:

```
<table id="table_mediaBank" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Media</th>
      <th>Beschrijving</th>
    </tr>
 </thead>

<tr>
    <td><a href="../images/redcont/123.jpg" class="hover"><img src="../images/redcont/123_tumb.jpg" class="mediabank-preview-thumbnail"/></a></td>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle;"> Beschrijving </td>
</tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready( function () {
    
    $('#table_mediaBank').DataTable( {
    fixedHeader: true,  
  stateSave: true,  
    select: true,
  
  select: {             
    info: false     
    },
        
  "aaSorting": [1, "desc"], // Sorteer Datum aflopend
                
      "columnDefs": [{ 
    "orderable": false,       // Verberg sorteer-icon van mutatie kolom
    "targets": [0],
    "searchable": false
    }, 
  ],
  
    
  "lengthMenu": [[15, 25, 50, 100, -1], [15, 25, 50, 100, "Alle"]],
    
            
            "oAria": {
        "sSortAscending":  ": activeer om kolom oplopend te sorteren",
        "sSortDescending": ": activeer om kolom aflopend te sorteren"
            }
        }
    
    } );


// Hover images
    var offsetX = 20;
    var offsetY = -400;
    $('a.hover').hover(function(e){ 
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $('<img id="largeImage" src="' + href + '" alt="image" />')
        .css({'top':e.pageY + offsetY,'left':e.pageX + offsetX})
        .appendTo('body');
    }, function(){
        $('#largeImage').remove();
    });
    $('a.hover').mousemove(function(e){
        $('#largeImage').css({'top':e.pageY + offsetY,'left':e.pageX + offsetX});
    });
    $('a.hover').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });

} );
```

Answer (score 0):

I recreated your problem by copying your one row of data multiple times, to force a second page of data.

To fix the issue, I moved your "Hover images" code from after the DataTables initialization to before it:

The new structure:

```
$(document).ready( function () {

  // your "hover images" code here:
  var offsetX = 20;
  ...
 
  $('#table_mediaBank').DataTable( {
    // your DataTables definition here   
  } );
 
} );
```

The change works in this specific case because all of the HTML table's data is available to the "hover" event handlers first - and then, after that, DataTables hides some of the HTML table data, for those rows not in the current page.

I expect this approach would not work if (as is often the case) it is DataTables which is responsible for loading the data - for example from an ajax source.

---

***Update***

For a more flexible approach, especially for data which is loaded directly by DataTables, you can use the following two features:

- the DataTables [`initComplete`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete) option, for the initial display event.
- The DataTables [`draw`](https://datatables.net/reference/event/draw) event, to capture when table data is re-drawn.

You can place all your "on hover" code into a function, and then call that function using the above two DataTables events.

In this case, the structure of your code would be as follows:

```js
$(document).ready( function () {

  var table = $('#table_mediaBank').DataTable( {
    "initComplete": function() {
      bindHoverImages();
    },
    // your other DataTables set-up code here
  } );

  table.on( 'draw', function () {
    bindHoverImages();
  } );

  function bindHoverImages() {
    // your on hover code here
  }

} );
```

Now, there is no need to ensure your binding code runs before your DataTables initialization.

(Note how you need to give your DataTable a variable name: `var table` for this to work.)

Comment: Thanks Andrewjames. That resolved my problem, but I don't understand why. Why are the hover events not applied when they are inside the ready function?

The additional notes are copy/paste failures.

Comment: I think my answer about moving the hover event handlers outside of the "document ready" function was a bad idea - sorry about that. It is probably a lot safer to leave it inside the "document ready" function - but place it before the DataTables initialization code. I have updated my answer, and tried to provide some additional notes. Both approaches (my original one and this new one) rely on the same basic fact: The event handlers do their binding before DataTables has a chance to hide any data from the DOM.

Comment: Thank you! I understand it.